# How to best write a long list of "or" "and" "not" operators?

Tags: python, boolean, openpyxl, neat

I am using Python/Openpyxl to search through strings in an Excel spreadsheet and sum up the numerical values. How do I write/format my script to have multiple OR, NOT, AND operators? (Sorry I appreciate this is probably a very basic question, but I am very new to coding!).

My script (excerpt) is currently this:

```
if 'Bananas' in cell.value or 'Apples' in cell.value:
```

However, I would like to write something longer, and ideally in a 'neat', extendable format, such as:

```
if:
 - 'Bananas'

or:
 - 'Apples'
 - 'Oranges'

and:
 - 'Large'

not:
 - 'Unripe'

...in cell.value:
```

Can someone tell me how I can format/write this in proper Python script? (Ideally in a format I can extend to, say, 20+ [or, and, not] conditions)

Comment: Is the _structure_ of the comparisons always the same?  i.e. do you always have one or more `if` conditions, and one or more `or` conditions, and one or more `and` conditions, and one or more `not` conditions?  Or can the structure change also?

Comment: Use `any` and `all`. E.g., `any(x in cell.value for x in ['Bananas', 'Apple'])`.

Comment: `in` does not distribute over boolean operations, so you can't reduce a bunch of membership tests to a single membership test.

Comment: @JohnGordon There is only one if conditions, but multiple and/or/not conditions, e.g. "if ('Bananas' in cell.value or 'Apples' in cell.value and 'large' in cell.value not 'unripe' in cell.value):"

Comment: @chepner  How can I add "AND" or "NOT" conditions to this? E.g. `if any(x in cell.value for x in ['apples', 'bananas']) not (any x in cell.value for x in ['unripe']):` (but this doesn't work, invalid syntax)

Comment: You may still need `and` and `or` to combine calls to `any` and `all`, using `not` as needed to negate things.

Answer (score 0):

```
if_values = ['Bananas', 'Apples', 'Oranges']
and_values = ['Large']
not_values = ['Unripe']

if any(item in cell.value for item in if_values) \
    and any(item in cell.value for item in and_values) \
    and not any(item in cell.value for item in not_values):
```